# How to add DLL reference to a c++ project in a native application?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013

I want to reference some DLLs in my C++ project in VS2013. I searched and found out that it could be done by right-clicking on
project node in solution explorer and select add reference. But when I did as said another window appeared instead of Reference
Manager one. Where is the problem? How can I add my DLLs to my project rather than copying them in same folder with `.exe`
output?
The reference node also does not appear in solution explorer. I tried show it by clicking "show all files", but it still does
not appear!

**EDIT:** I edited the title according to  drescherjm`s comment.

[image: I did right-click on project node and select add references.]

[image]

Comment: I believe that is for .NET / CLR and will not work with a native application.

Comment: @drescherjm, please explain more. I am not professional!

Comment: The explanation is you can't do what you are trying to do. Just copy your dlls to the same folder as your .exe.

Comment: If you want to automate this write a batch file that copies your dlls and make it a post build step.

Comment: What I do in general to not copy the dlls in the folder of the executable is right click on the project -> properties -> Debug -> Enviroment. And I set the  following variable: `PATH=<folder where is the dll>;%PATH%`

Comment: @BugsFree, it errors "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)".

Comment: @BugsFree, I changed my solution platform from `Win32` to `x64` and the error removed. Please post your comment as answer to let me accept and it maybe cause to save some time for somebody. If possible explain a little about dll referencing for .NET Vs. native apps mentioned by drescherjm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a native C++ project in Visual Studio in order to not copy the dlls in the folder of the executable you can right-click on the project -> properties -> Debug -> Enviroment and set the following variable: `PATH=<folder where the dll is>;%PATH%`

I'm not a great expert of C# but what I know is that in a .NET application, [in order to use a component in your application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx), you need to add a reference to it. For default, the dll is locally copy and deployed with your application; to prevent this, you have to register the dll in the GAC([Global Assembly Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/yf1d93sz(v=vs.110).aspx)).